# Origin of Higgs ghosts

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, ghosts

In *M. Veltman's Diagrammatica*, appendix E, one can find the full Standard Model lagrangian. Some sectors (e.g fermion-Higgs and weak sectors) contain so-called Higgs ghosts $\phi^+,\phi^-$ and $\phi^0$.

> Are Higgs ghosts  Faddeev-Popov ghosts?

If so,

> why does the Higgs field, not being a gauge field, yield Faddeev-Popov ghosts?

If not,

> in which sense are they *ghosts*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Higgs ghosts are not [Faddeev-Popov ghosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost). (For starters, the Faddeev-Popov ghosts in the standard model are Grassmann-odd, while the Higgs ghosts are Grassmann-even.)

The Higgs ghosts are [Goldstone bosons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson) for the spontaneously broken part of the electroweak symmetry $SU(2) \times U(1)$, which, popularly speaking, get eaten by the massive gauge bosons $W^{\pm}$ and $Z$ via the [Higgs mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism). They are ghosts in the sense that they are not physical fields but rather gauge-dependent artifacts.

The Higgs ghosts are not so-called *bad ghosts,* which would have wrong sign in their kinetic terms, yield negative norm states & break unitarity.